Information about inverse limits in R-mod category
I would like to find a book or some references about inverse limits in R-Mod category but I can’t find it.If you can give me some references I will apareciate it.

Not sure if this is quite what you are looking for, but Weibel has a section on "Derived Functors of the Inverse Limit" in his book Introduction to Homological Algebra (see page 80). This goes in depth about the (co)homology constructed from the inverse limit, which is what will ultimately set the inverse limit in $R$-mod apart from that of some nonabelian category.
If you are looking more for an introduction to the inverse limit as a mathematical object, I would take a look at Riehl's Category Theory in Context, which has a chapter on limits/colimits and gives some examples/explanation on the inverse limit. Personally, I think the best way to think about the inverse limits is in terms of its universal property / commutative diagram, hence why I recommend Riehl.
Hope this helps.
